# Writing to DB tables

Tags: java, sql, database, file-io

I am trying to write a new record to two database tables which are called **item** and **supplier**.

I have a class that handles the database connection and SQL statements. I am using a large form in a class called ItemEntryScreen where I am using the following:

```
private void writeItemRecord()
{
     if ( DataBaseHandler.makeConnectionTofireplaceDB() == -1)
       {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (frame, "Unable to connect to database table (Item)");
       }
     else  // Ok, so first read data from the text fields
       {
           // Read data from form and store data     
           String suppliercode = suppliercodeTxtField.getText();
           String suppliername = suppliernameTxtField.getText();
           String address = addressTxtField.getText();


           // Create a Item oject
           Item item = new Item();

           // Set the attributes for the Item object
           item.setSuppliercode(suppliercode);
           item.setSuppliername(suppliername);
           item.setAddress(address);

           // Write Item record.  Method writeToItemTable() returns
           // 0 of OK writing record, -1 if there is a problem.  I store
           // the returned value in a variable called error.
           int error = DataBaseHandler.writeTosupplierTable(item.getSuppliercode(),item.getSuppliername(),item.getAddress());

           // Check if there is a problem writing the record, in 
           // which case error will contain -1                                         
           if (error == -1)
             {
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (frame, "Problem writing record to Item Table");
             }

          // Clear the form - actual method is coded below
          clearForm();

          // Close database connection.  Report an error message
          // if there is a problem.
          if ( DataBaseHandler.closeConnection() == -1 )
             {
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (frame, "Problem closing data base conection");
             }
        }
    }                    

/**
 *  Method to write a Item record
*/
private void writesupplierRecord()
{
     // Check to see if we can connect to database table
     if ( DataBaseHandler.makeConnectionTofireplaceDB() == -1)
       {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (frame, "Unable to connect to database table (Item)");
       }
     else  // Ok, so first read data from the text fields
       {
           // Read data from form and store data     

           String itemname = itemnameTxtField.getText();
           String itemcode = itemcodeTxtField.getText();
           String description = descriptionTxtField.getText();
           String unitprice = unitpriceTxtField.getText();
           String style = styleTxtField.getText();
           String finish = finishTxtField.getText();
           String stock = stockTxtField.getText();

           // Convert priceStr to a float
           Float fvar = Float.valueOf(unitprice);
           float newprice = fvar.floatValue();

           Float svar = Float.valueOf(stock);
           float newstock = svar.floatValue();

           // Create a Item oject
           Item item = new Item();

           // Set the attributes for the Item object
           item.setItemname (itemname);
           item.setItemcode (itemcode);
           item.setDescription (description);
           item.setUnitprice (newprice);
           item.setStock(newstock);
           item.setStyle(style);
           item.setFinish(finish);

           // Write Item record.  Method writeToItemTable() returns
           // 0 of OK writing record, -1 if there is a problem.  I store
           // the returned value in a variable called error.
           int error = DataBaseHandler.writeToitemTable(item.getItemname(),
                                                        item.getItemcode(),
                                                        item.getDescription(),
                                                        item.getUnitprice(), 
                                                        item.getStock(),
                                                        item.getStyle(),
                                                        item.getFinish()
                                                        );

           // Check if there is a problem writing the record, in 
           // which case error will contain -1                                         
           if (error == -1)
             {
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (frame, "Problem writing record to Item Table");
             }

          // Clear the form - actual method is coded below
          clearForm();

          // Close database connection.  Report an error message
          // if there is a problem.
          if ( DataBaseHandler.closeConnection() == -1 )
             {
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (frame, "Problem closing data base conection");
             }
        }

 }  // End
```

The above code compiles!

```
static public int writeToitemTable(String itemnameIn, String itemcodeIn, String descriptionIn,
                                        float unitpriceIn, float stockIn, String styleIn, String finishIn)
    {
          // Variable to hold the SQL query
          String SQLString;

          // Build a string containing the SQL INSERT instruction to be used later
          SQLString = "INSERT INTO item VALUES ('" + itemcodeIn + "','" + itemnameIn + "','" + descriptionIn + "','" + unitpriceIn + "','" 
                                            + stockIn + "','" + styleIn + "','" + finishIn + "')";


           try
              {
                    // The createStatement() method creates a Statement object.  Object will be
                    // attached to my reference variable (statement) defined at the top of class.
                    statement = connectionTofireplaceDB.createStatement();

                    // The executeUpdate() statement can be used here to execute an 
                    // SQL INSERT instruction.
                    statement.executeUpdate (SQLString);

              }
            catch (SQLException exception)
              {
                   return (-1);     // Return -1 if problem writing record to file

              }

            return (0);   // Return with 0 if record successfully written 

      } // End

  static public int writeTosupplierTable(String suppliernameIn, String suppliercodeIn, String addressIn)
    {
          // Variable to hold the SQL query
          String SQLString;

          // Build a string containing the SQL INSERT instruction to be used later
          SQLString = "INSERT INTO supplier VALUES ('" + suppliernameIn + "','" + suppliercodeIn + "','" + addressIn + "')";


           try
              {
                    // The createStatement() method creates a Statement object.  Object will be
                    // attached to my reference variable (statement) defined at the top of class.
                    statement = connectionTofireplaceDB.createStatement();

                    // The executeUpdate() statement can be used here to execute an 
                    // SQL INSERT instruction.
                    statement.executeUpdate (SQLString);

              }
            catch (SQLException exception)
              {
                   return (-1);     // Return -1 if problem writing record to file

              }

            return (0);   // Return with 0 if record successfully written 

      } // End
```

When I enter details into the form and hit the submit button, I am getting a return value of -1 which results in a message box being displayed that states there was a problem writing to the database.  Why?

**Update**

These are the error messages I can getting:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ItemEntryScreen.writeItemRecord(ItemEntryScreen.java:392)
    at ItemEntryScreen.actionPerformed(ItemEntryScreen.java:348)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6038)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3265)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5803)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2058)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4410)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2116)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4322)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:3986)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:3916)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2102)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2429)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:273)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:183)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:173)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:168)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:160)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:121)
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at the fields of the `SQLException` to see what the error is?

Comment: `catch (SQLException exception) { return (-1); }` > you must work on your exception handling strategy! If you do, finding the bug becomes easy!

Comment: String concatenation for SQL query building? That's a very bad idea, that unfortunately tends to propagate uncontrollably...

Comment: @home: "Exceptions? C didn't need no exceptions!"

Comment: @thkala: I don't get that - what do you mean?

Comment: @home: `return -1` is a common C convention for indicating error conditions to the caller of a function, since C does not have exceptions...

Comment: @thkala: it's not necessarily about returning a status code, it's more about the missing printStackTrace() or logging. I agree that returning a code is not an issue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, print the stacktrace to find the error.

Second, I have seen people are having these troubles because of "Statement". Use "PreparedStatement" in places where the values are about to change.Most probably your issue will be solved if you do the second suggestion

Third, close the connection using finally() block or something

Answer (score 1):

Look at my code below, and try to implement it as its here.... i hope it will run smoothly.. Once you start getting your desired query result, modify it to your heart content for further R&D.

```
import java.sql.Connection;

import java.sql.DriverManager;

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

import java.sql.ResultSet;

import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import java.sql.Statement;

import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JTable;

import com.my.views.*;


public class DBDiary {

    Connection conn;
    EntryDisplay entryD;


    public DBDiary(){

        this.getConn();

    }

    public Connection getConn(){

        try {
            conn = getConnection();

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println("Connection Couldnt be Obtained");
        }
           return conn;
    }


    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {

        String drivers = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
        String username = "root";
        String password = "root";

        System.setProperty(drivers,"");

        return DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);

    }

    public void createTable() {

        Statement stat = null;
        String sql = "create table items(item varchar(30), cost DOUBLE(12,3),day integer,month varchar(15), year integer);";
        if (conn != null){

            try {

                 stat = conn.createStatement();

            } catch (SQLException e) {

                System.out.println("Connection Couldnt be Obtained");
            }

            if (stat != null){

                try {
                    stat.executeUpdate(sql);
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    //System.out.println("Table already Exists");
                }       
            }

        }
    }


    public void addItems(String item, double cost,int day, String month, int year) {

        PreparedStatement pstat = null;

        String sql = "INSERT INTO ITEMS Values(?,?,?,?,?);";

        if (conn != null){

            try {

                 pstat = conn.prepareStatement(sql);


            } catch (SQLException e) {

                System.out.println("Connection Couldnt be Obtained");
            }

        }

        if (pstat != null) {

            try {

                 pstat.setString(1, item);
                 pstat.setDouble(2, cost);
                 pstat.setInt(3, day);
                 pstat.setString(4, month);
                 pstat.setInt(5,year);
                 pstat.executeUpdate();

            } catch (SQLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Insertion of the entry was unsuccessful");
            }
        }


    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

    DBDiary db = new DBDiary();
    db.createTable();
    db.addItems("Cards", 40.00,29, "Mar", 2012);


    }
```

Comment: A very useful post, thank you. But I still cannot seem to solve this issue. However thank you again for trying.

Comment: I am closing the connection using:
static public int closeConnection()
        {
         //Code for close in here}

However are you referring to when I make the insert motions to close and then re-open the database connection for each insert?

Comment: I don't the last package. TBH its fine. Ill try figure this out myself. Thanks for trying...

Comment: the driver loads successfully :)

I have another class set up where I read in all of the item table data and display it and that seems to work fine. =/

Edit:
But then again, the operation deals with a single table, not both.